# How to properly pass and return by reference between function inside a class

Tags: php, callback, bindparam, return-by-reference

I create a class that hold `mysqli` object link with a private function to generate params that needed by `bind_params` function which then will be used by this function:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

Since, `bind_param` need to pass value by reference, so I create a the function like this:

```
// $values is taken from $_POST's values
private function &params($values) {

    // Generate first value for bind_params like: 'ssis'
    $param_type = '';
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $param_type .= gettype($value)[0];
    }

    // Generate the rest value for bind_params
    $params[] = & $param_type;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
        $params[] = & $values[$i];
    }

    // The returned values should be like { 'ssi', $str_value, $str_value, $int_value }
    return $params;
}
```

How I execute prepared statement is like this:

```
function insert_prepared($query, $posted) {
    $params = &$this->params(array_values($posted));
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    if ($stmt) {
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, now the problem is why `call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params)` still complaints about **expected to be a reference**?

Did the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) said the function should be written like `function &params($values)`?

What did I missing?

Comment: call_user_func_array() expects that param1 be a callable function param 2 an array of arguments